# Fastify disable schema validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I'm looking for the best way to disable programmatically the json-schema validation for all routes in a fastify instance:

```js
module.exports = async (fastify, opts) => {
  fastify.get('/stations.json', {schema: opts.schema}, async req => {
    return {
      ...
    };
  });
}
```

this is a working way:

```
  ...global config definitions...

  fastify.addHook('onRoute', route => {
    if (config.validation === false && route.schema) {
      route.schema = null
      console.log('Route disable:',route.path)
    }
  })
```

The problem with this solution is that it breaks fastify `swagger-ui`, instead I what simply to disable the validation in routes, keeping the schema definition for each one.
I guess it could be done with the method: `fastify.setValidatorCompiler()`
but I'm not very clear how I could use it.
I would like to bypass executing validation functions in routes if possible, not just executing "empty functions".

Answer (score 2):

Based on fastify [docs](https://fastify.dev/docs/v4.13.x/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/), validatorCompiler **is** a function that gets data, validate it and returns either `{value: true/false}` or `{error: your error}`.

`setValidatorCompiler` is a function that needs to return `validatorCompiler`  (which is a function).

Therefore, you can set a validatorCompiler on the `fastify` instance, that will return always `true`.

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')();

fastify.setValidatorCompiler(() => {
  return () => ({ value: true });
  // ----^ this is the validatorCompiler
});
```

I didn't tested this code, but, based on the docs page, it should work.

Comment: not working using `{value:true}` object

Answer (score 1):

schema validation is done by ajv plugin which can be disabled by using the code below

```
 const fastify=require('fastify')
  ({
  ajv:{customOptions:{strict:false}}
})
```